# english documentation of tkz-euclid

Tags: tikz-pgf, documentation, tkz-euclide

I just can't find the english documentation of tkz-euclid.

ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/README

says

> http://altermundus.fr (en franÃ§ais) or  http://altermundus.fr (in
>   english)   Documentation for printing will be ready soon.

Can you point me to it?

Comment: I don't think it exists. The author of `tkz-euclid` happens to be around here, but such a request should be addressed directly to him.

Comment: You should contact the author - his email is at the bottom of that page.

Comment: N'existe pas, malhereusement. :-/

Comment: With the next version but in several months ... you can ask questions directly by mail

Comment: Currently there is a (very extensive) manual in English on http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/TKZdoc-euclide.pdf.