# Can I enlarge lines in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm currently creating lecture notes for "Geometry and Topology". As we now arrived at part about euclidean geometry, I quite often have the situation that I need to visualize lines (not line segments, but lines).

For example, I have the following image (the code is at the end)

[image]

But `PQ` should be a line, so I need to "enlarge" the line segment `PQ`.
Usually, I would calculate the equation of PQ like this

```
m = (P.y - Q.y)/(P.x - Q.x) -- mind the special case of P.x = Q.x
P.y = m * P.x + t
<=> t = P.y - m*P.x
```

Then I would add two helping points `A` and `B`:

```
(enlarge by 0.5)
A.x := P.x - 0.5 
B.x := Q.x + 0.5
A.y = m*A.x + t
B.y = m*B.x + t
```

And finally I would draw the line `A - P - Q - B` which is my "enlarged line 'PQ'".

But this seems to be quite complicated to me for a task that could be done automatically. So is there a way in TikZ to enlarge lines?

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{point}=[circle,thick,draw=black,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=4pt,minimum height=4pt]
    \node (P)[point,label={[label distance=0cm]-90:$P$}] at (0,0) {};
    \node (Q)[point,label={[label distance=0cm]-90:$Q$}] at (5,1) {};
    \node (A)[point,label={[label distance=0cm]180:$\varphi_1(R)$}] at (2,2) {};
    \node (B)[point,label={[label distance=0cm]190:$\varphi_2(R)$}] at (1,3) {};

    \draw[very thick, enlarge] (P) edge node  {} (Q);
    \draw[very thick, red] (P) edge node {} (A);
    \draw[very thick, red] (P) edge node {} (B);
    \draw[very thick, green] (Q) edge node {} (A);
    \draw[very thick, green] (Q) edge node {} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related [TikZ: how to find the intersection of two extended lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29368/tikz-how-to-find-the-intersection-of-two-extended-lines) and [How to draw a line passing through a point and perpendicular to another?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19348/how-to-draw-a-line-passing-through-a-point-and-perpendicular-to-another).

Comment: You might also want to look at the `tkz-euclide` package for drawings like this. The syntax takes a bit of getting used to, but once you've got the hang of it, it makes drawing diagrams like this *much* easier.

Comment: @Jake: thanks, it works with `\draw ($(P)!-1cm!(Q)$) -- ($(Q)!-1cm!(P)$);` :-)

Comment: Could you add that as an answer?

Comment: Ok. But although I currenlty use the solution I have found with your help I would like to accept your answer acknowledge your help (and I think your answer might be cleaner ... although I don't completely understand it at the moment. For example, how does `tikz` decide how long the line PQ should be?)

Comment: The line drawn by `\tkzDrawLine` extends over the points by 20 % of the distance between the two points. You can adjust that amount using `\tkzDrawLine[add=0.1 and 0.4](P,Q)` to make the line extend by 10 % and 40 % of the distance, for example.

Comment: Oh, I've just seen that [tkz-euclide is documented in French only](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115362/5645). I did not think that I would need French after school.

Comment: Hehe, yeah, it was the same for me. It's not too difficult to figure out, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When using `tkz-euclide` to construct the drawing, you can indicate a line passing through two points using `\tkzDrawLine(P,Q)`, while the line segment would be drawn using `\tkzDrawSegment(P,Q)`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/P, 5/1/Q, 2/2/Phi1, 1/3/Phi2}

\tkzDrawSegments[red](P,Phi1 P,Phi2)
\tkzDrawSegments[blue](Q,Phi1 Q,Phi2)

\tkzDrawLine(P,Q)

\tkzDrawPoints(P,Q,Phi1,Phi2)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](P,Q)
\tkzLabelPoint[above left](Phi1){$\varphi_1(R)$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above left](Phi2){$\varphi_2(R)$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution looks very much the same as my solution when you use `\tkzSetUpPoint[shape=circle,size=10,color=black,fill=black]`.

Comment: What does `\usetkzobj{all}` do? Removing it seems to have no effect.

Comment: @moose: That command loads tools for drawing polygons, arcs and circles. It's actually not necessary for this code.

Comment: You cad just write \tkzDrawLine[add=0.1 and 0.2](P,Q) and play with 0.1 and 0.2. Thee are the percentages of the segment PQ this segment will be extended beyond the points. The first number (0.1) is for the extension beyond the first point, the second  number (0.2) is for the extension beyond the second point

Answer (score 10):

## Solution

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{point}=[circle,thick,draw=black,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=4pt,minimum height=4pt]
    \node (P)[point,label={[label distance=0cm]-90:$P$}] at (0,0) {};
    \node (Q)[point,label={[label distance=0cm]-90:$Q$}] at (5,1) {};
    \node (A)[point,label={[label distance=0cm]180:$\varphi_1(R)$}] at (2,2) {};
    \node (B)[point,label={[label distance=0cm]190:$\varphi_2(R)$}] at (1,3) {};

    \draw[very thick] (P) edge node  {} (Q);
    \draw[very thick, red] (P) edge node {} (A);
    \draw[very thick, red] (P) edge node {} (B);
    \draw[very thick, blue] (Q) edge node {} (A);
    \draw[very thick, blue] (Q) edge node {} (B);

    \draw[very thick] ($(P)!-1cm!(Q)$) -- ($(Q)!-1cm!(P)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Explanation

The key line is

```
\draw[very thick] ($(P)!-1cm!(Q)$) -- ($(Q)!-1cm!(P)$);
```

`$(P)!-1cm!(Q)$` defines a point that is `1cm` more in direction `P` when you look at the line `PQ`. The same for `($(Q)!-1cm!(P)$)`. This way, you have "enlarged" the line `PQ` by `1cm` in both directions.

## Image

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Another solution would be to just use `shorten >` and `shorten <`:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{point}=[circle,thick,draw=black,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=4pt,minimum height=4pt]
    \node (P)[point,label={[label distance=0cm]-90:$P$}] at (0,0) {};
    \node (Q)[point,label={[label distance=0cm]-90:$Q$}] at (5,1) {};
    \node (A)[point,label={[label distance=0cm]180:$\varphi_1(R)$}] at (2,2) {};
    \node (B)[point,label={[label distance=0cm]190:$\varphi_2(R)$}] at (1,3) {};

    \draw[very thick, shorten >=-1cm, shorten <=-1cm] (P) edge node  {} (Q);
    \draw[very thick, red] (P) edge node {} (A);
    \draw[very thick, red] (P) edge node {} (B);
    \draw[very thick, green] (Q) edge node {} (A);
    \draw[very thick, green] (Q) edge node {} (B);

    \path[use as bounding box] (-1,1) rectangle (6, 3.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note, however, that TikZ will not extend the bounding box automatically, which is why I had to add `\path[use as bounding box] ...;`

Answer (score 4):

With PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[linejoin=1,linecap=1](8,6)
    \pstGeonode
    [
        PointName={\varphi_2(R),\varphi_1(R),default},
        PosAngle={180,180,-90},
        PointNameSep={24pt,24pt,12pt},
    ](3,5.5){T}(4,3){B}(1,1){P}(7,2){Q}
    \psline[linecolor=red](B)(P)(T)
    \psline[linecolor=blue](B)(Q)(T)
    \pcline[nodesep=-1](P)(Q)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can the lines be drawn behind the circles?

Comment: @Jake: Yes. Redraw the circles after drawing the lines. The circles given above are automatically provided by `\pstGeonode` as a useful bonus as long as `linecolor=black`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It is sad that redrawing the circles is the only solution, since it is not best practice and unnecessarily takes up space in the resulting file.

Comment: @Jake: Then prevent `\pstGeonode` from providing bonus circles when constructing nodes via `PointSymbol=none`. So we draw (rather than redraw) the circles manually after constructing the lines. It will save the data storage which in turn reduce the carbon emission.

Comment: That's a much better idea, thank you. +1

Comment: @Jake: Thank  you for upvoting. :-)