# Where can I find documentation for tkz-graph in english

Tags: tkz-collection, tutorials, tkz-graph

The `tkz-graph` / `tkz-berge` packages are really useful for making graphs. The official documentation available on CTAN, is however not much help. The [documentation for `tkz-berge`](http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-berge/doc/tkz-berge-screen.pdf) only document the high-level functions, but not the low level like `\Vertex` and `\Edge`. These are documented as part of `tkz-graph`, but that is [in French](http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-graph/doc/tkz-graph-screen.pdf).

I am use to some steep learning curves in latex, but learning french in order to read the documentation is a little too steep for me. Does anybody know of an English version of the documentation for `tkz-graph`?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think any exists, but [Alain](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144/alain-matthes) will know for sure I suppose.

Comment: I'm sorry but currently I do not have enough time to spend with my packages and TeX. It is possible that I resume development soon for updates and documentation in English. If you have specific questions,  I can give some explanations. My email is given on my website or in my documentation.

Comment: Related [english documentation of tkz-euclid](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115362/english-documentation-of-tkz-euclid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in comments, there is unfortunately no English documentation available. Some of the options available to you are then to

- try to make sense of things from just looking at the examples in the documentation;
- ask specific questions about features in the package here;
- ask Alain directly, via email.